# OOP PHP based on select values

Tags: php, forms, oop, post, mysqli

I am doing some practicing with OOP in PHP, and am having issues with submitting form data involving subclasses.

What I am trying to do: submit form data based on the *type* of product it is (generic, tool, or electronic).  My concern comes from not being able to submit a form that can differentiate between the different product types.

Here's the `Product Class` (the base class):

```
<?php
require_once('connectvars.php');

// Base class!!
class Product {
    // Inheritable properties
    protected $title;
    protected $description;
    protected $price;

    // Getters
    public function getTitle() {
        return $this->title;
    }
    public function getDescription() {
        return $this->description;
    }
    public function getPrice() {
        return $this->price;
    }

    // Setters
    public function setTitle($title) {
        $this->title = $title;
    }
    public function setDescription($description) {
        $this->description = $description;
    }
    public function setPrice($price) {
        $this->price = $price;
    }

    public function insertProduct() {
        $dbc    = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PW, DB_NAME);
        $query  = "INSERT INTO addedProducts VALUES (0,'$this->title', '$this->description', '$this->price', '', '', '')";

        mysqli_query($dbc, $query)
            or die("Error adding to database");

        mysqli_close($dbc);
    }
}
?>
```

Here's a subclass I made called `Tools`:

```
<?php
require_once('connectvars.php');
require_once('Product.php');

class Tools extends Product {
    // Defined properties specific to Tools class
    private $shipper;
    private $weight;

    // Getters
    public function getShipper() {
        return $this->shipper;
    }
    public function getWeight() {
        return $this->weight;
    }

    // Setters
    public function setShipper($shipper) {
        $this->shipper = $shipper;
    }
    public function setWeight($weight) {
        $this->weight = $weight;
    }

    public function insertTool() {
        $dbc    = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PW, DB_NAME);
        $query  = "INSERT INTO addedProducts VALUES (0,'$this->title', '$this->description', '$this->price', '$this->shipper', '$this->weight', '')";

        mysqli_query($dbc, $query)
            or die("Error adding to database");

        mysqli_close($dbc);
    }
}
?>
```

This is where I am running into problems:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
   <title>Product Entry</title>
</head>
<body>
    <select name="prodType" id="prodType">
        <option value="" selected="selected">Select...</option>
        <option value="general">General</option>
        <option value="tools">Tools</option>
        <option value="electronics">Electronics</option>
    </select>
    <br/><br/>
<?php
//require_once('connectvars.php');
require_once('Product.php');
require_once('Electronics.php');
require_once('Tools.php');

$product    = new Product();
$tool       = new Tools();
$electronic = new Electronics();

if (isset($_POST['submit']) && (isset($_POST['prodType']) == 'general')) {
    $product_form = false;

    $product->setTitle($_POST['title']);
    $product->setDescription($_POST['description']);
    $product->setPrice($_POST['price']);             

    $product->insertProduct();

    /*$tool->setTitle($_POST['title']);
    $tool->setDescription($_POST['description']);
    $tool->setPrice($_POST['price']);
    $tool->setShipper($_POST['shipper']);
    $tool->setWeight($_POST['weight']);
    if (!empty($tool->getTitle()) && !empty($tool->getDescription()) &&     is_numeric($tool->getPrice()) && !empty($tool->getShipper()) && !empty($tool-    >getWeight())) {
        echo 'Tool submitted <br/>';
        //echo '<a href="addProduct.php">Go Back</a>';
        $tool->insertTool();
    }
} else {
    $product_form = true;
}

if ($product_form) {
?>
    <form method="POST" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>">
        <label for="title"><strong>Product Title</strong></label>
        <br/>
        <input type="text" id="title" name="title" value="<?php echo $product->getTitle();?>"/>
        <br/><br/>
        <label for="description"><strong>Description</strong></label>
        <br/>
        <input type="text" id="description" name="description" value="<?php echo $product->getDescription();?>"/>
        <br/><br/>
        <label for="price"><strong>Price</strong></label>
        <br/>
        <input type="text" id="price" name="price" value="<?php echo $product->getPrice();?>"/>
        <br/><br/>            
         <!--For Tools -->
        <label for="shipper"><strong>Shipper Info</strong></label>
        <br/>
        <select name="shipper" id="shipper">
            <option value="none" selected="selected">--</option>
            <option value="usps">USPS</option>
            <option value="fedex">FedEx</option>
            <option value="ups">UPS</option>
        </select>
        <br/><br/>
        <label for="weight"><strong>Weight</strong></label>
        <br/>
        <input type="text" id="weight" name="weight" value="<?php echo $tool->getWeight();?>"/>
        <br/><br/>            
         <!--For Electronics -->
        <label for="recyclable"><strong>Recyclable?</strong></label>
        <br/>
        <select name="recyclable" id="recyclable">
            <option value="none" selected="selected">--</option>
            <option value="yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="no">No</option>
        </select>            
        <br/><br/>
        <input type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" value="Submit Product"/>
    </form>
<?php
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

I'm sure there's a fairly straightforward solution, but I'm no longer thinking about this correctly anymore -_-.  Any suggestions?

Comment: What is the actual behavior? Is there any error message?

Comment: @FelisCatus, there is no error message--when I select 'general' and press submit, the form clears out but nothing is sent to the database

Comment: Put your prodType select option into inside the form. Thia may be overcomes your problem

Comment: Where do you select 'general'. Am i missing a `select` box?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do the following:

1. Move all of your calculations to the top of the file.
2. Move your prodType into the form.
3. I am displaying the form always.  In 1 instance it is to edit, in another it is to create.  But you will want to add a hidden input for the "product_id"

Like this:

```
<?php
require_once('Product.php');
require_once('Electronics.php');
require_once('Tools.php');

$product    = new Product();
$tool       = new Tools();
$electronic = new Electronics();
if (isset($_POST['submit'])){
     $prodType = $_POST['prodType'];
     if($prodType == 'general') {
        $product_form = false;
        $product->setTitle($_POST['title']);
        $product->setDescription($_POST['description']);
        $product->setPrice($_POST['price']);             
        $product->insertProduct();
    } else if($prodType == 'tools') {

    } else if ($prodType == 'elecronics') {
    } else {
        // echo this message in the form. 
        $msg = 'Invalid product type';
    }
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Product Entry</title>
</head>
<body>
<form method="POST" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>">
    <select name="prodType" id="prodType">
        <option value="" selected="selected">Select...</option>
        <option value="general">General</option>
        <option value="tools">Tools</option>
        <option value="electronics">Electronics</option>
    </select>
    <br/><br/>
    <label for="title"><strong>Product Title</strong></label>
    <br/>
    <input type="text" id="title" name="title" value="<?php echo $product->getTitle();?>"/>
    <br/><br/>
    <label for="description"><strong>Description</strong></label>
    <br/>
    <input type="text" id="description" name="description" value="<?php echo $product->getDescription();?>"/>
    <br/><br/>
    <label for="price"><strong>Price</strong></label>
    <br/>
    <input type="text" id="price" name="price" value="<?php echo $product->getPrice();?>"/>
    <br/><br/>            
    <!--For Tools -->
    <label for="shipper"><strong>Shipper Info</strong></label>
    <br/>
    <select name="shipper" id="shipper">
        <option value="none" selected="selected">--</option>
        <option value="usps">USPS</option>
        <option value="fedex">FedEx</option>
        <option value="ups">UPS</option>
    </select>
    <br/><br/>
    <label for="weight"><strong>Weight</strong></label>
    <br/>
    <input type="text" id="weight" name="weight" value="<?php echo $tool->getWeight();?>"/>
    <br/><br/>            
    <!--For Electronics -->
    <label for="recyclable"><strong>Recyclable?</strong></label>
    <br/>
    <select name="recyclable" id="recyclable">
        <option value="none" selected="selected">--</option>
        <option value="yes">Yes</option>
        <option value="no">No</option>
    </select>            
    <br/><br/>
    <input type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" value="Submit Product"/>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Note: You should use and learn [composer](http://getcomposer.org).  It is a must have tool to autoload your class files.

Comment: I can get it to submit a 'general' product properly, but cannot submit a 'tools' product.  This is the kind of validation I am attempting to do: `if (isset($_POST['submit']) && (isset($_POST['prodType']) == 'tools')) { //$tool->insertTool(); }` Note: I am attempting to do this _after_ I created the validation (like you suggested above) for submitting a general product

Comment: Thanks! I've been completely 'brain-farting' the past few days, and this is exactly what I was looking to do!